# Conditionally check a string in TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript

Given the following generic:

```
type WheneverPossible<T extends "boy" | "girl"> =  ...
```

I want to check conditionally on this generic like the following:

```
type WheneverPossible<T extends "boy" | "girl"> =  T === "boy" ? { numOfBalls: number } : { numOfDolls: number }
```

Is there a possibility to do something like this in TypeScript?

Comment: You're so close – use `T extends "boy"` instead of `T === "boy"`. [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible just use the `extends` keyword

```
type WheneverPossible<T extends "boy" | "girl"> =  T extends "boy"
  ? { numOfBalls: number }
  : { numOfDolls: number }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFhAdhAbhATgBQPYGdcCWARgDYQA8AKlBAB7BIAmuUAREdiK1AD5sDmBdCVYA+KAF4oUanQaJmbDlygB+KAG8oiAK4BbAPIAzAEIBDEiVwAubfqIYoAXyi2tuw0YAi2Szbt6DujOAFBhjBAAxiRm6NCR2Ii4wFAMybbkANI09EwsAOTK+bxQ+YLC+aIAFADWBIy2mQCUkuLwSKgYOPjEZFmiYWnAVYWc+U0AdB7G5n4hQyPlJONT+sY+cyEA9FtQAALAuAC0dJCRwCfo6Njo8xDJI0WT096+VmE7+4cntGcXGNdbgsykJls81qYLFYgA)